# How to paste together a vector element with the previuos according to a condition

Tags: r, string, loops, if-statement

I'm getting data from a web source with `rvest` and then I got a vector, say `x`, which has a length different from my other vectors (so I can't combine them into a table). Getting to the point: The reason is that every time I see the element `'nuovo'` (position `x[11]` ) in the vec, I know It should be pasted with exactly the previous, then i should also cancel out the element 'nuovo' because I need a 25 length vector.

```
x  = c("Vetrina" ,"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina",
"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina", "Vetrina",
"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina",
"Vetrina" ,"nuovo" ,"Vetrina",
"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina",
"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina",
"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina", "Vetrina",
"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina", "Vetrina",
"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina")

length(x) = 26
```

and then I need `x` to be like:

```
x  = c("Vetrina" ,"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina",
"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina", "Vetrina",
"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina",
"Vetrina nuovo","Vetrina",
"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina",
"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina",
"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina", "Vetrina",
"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina", "Vetrina",
"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina")

length(x) = 25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
# First find the elements we wish to remove
nuovo = which(x=="nuovo")
x = x[-nuovo]

# Now paste into the preceding elements.
nuovo2 = nuovo - seq_along(nuovo)
x[nuovo2] = paste(x[nuovo2], "nuovo")
```

Similarly, you could instead reverse the order of these operations and paste before removing

```
x[nuovo - 1] = paste(x[nuovo - 1], "nuovo")
x = x[-nuovo]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution in `base` R. First you get the position of `nuovo` then `paste` it to the previous position. Finally you remove `nuovo` positions.

```
x <- c("Vetrina" ,"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina",
       "Vetrina" ,"Vetrina", "Vetrina",
       "Vetrina" ,"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina",
       "Vetrina" ,"nuovo" ,"Vetrina",
       "Vetrina" ,"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina",
       "Vetrina" ,"Vetrina" ,"Vetrina",
       "Vetrina" ,"Vetrina", "Vetrina",
       "Vetrina" ,"Vetrina", "Vetrina",
       "Vetrina" ,"nuovo")

pos <- x == "nuovo"
x[c(pos[-1], F)] <- paste(x[c(pos[-1], F)], "nuovo")
x <- x[!pos]

length(x)
> 24
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility involving `lag()` from `dplyr()`:

```
x <- ifelse(lag(x, default = first(x)) == "nuovo", paste(x, lag(x)), x)
x[-grepl("nuovo", x)]

 [1] "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"      
 [6] "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"       "Vetrina nuovo" "Vetrina"      
[11] "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"      
[16] "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"      
[21] "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"       "Vetrina"
```